# Oracle database parallel processing plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, job-scheduling

So I have this Oracle database job running all in one PL-SQL block. As we added more parts for this job to process, it began to take too long for it to run. As these parts have different "part types", I decided to break my query down by "part type" and create 4 jobs for the 4 "part types" to run in parallel.

Do you know of any way to execute these 4 jobs in parallel in one PL-SQL block, instead of creating 4 separate jobs? I am using task-scheduler + SQL-PLUS to schedule.

Comment: Why don't you want to create four jobs to run four separate tasks?

Comment: Well if we were to scale this to where we want, we would eventually require about 25 jobs. My higher ups don't want that. We have a server specifically for this. It's going to be Oracle that's doing the bulk of the processing. Can task-scheduler handle 25 batch calls to SQL-PLUS if I separate them by 5 seconds each? what are your thoughts?

Comment: Why not run the PL/SQL blocks in the background (and thus in parallel) through `dbms_scheduler`?

Comment: I was thinking about that. I may want to go that route. Perhaps it was my mind wanting to use what I already know. However, I'm sure this just takes parameters similar to task-scheduler. I will look into it. Also it's probably more reliable than task-scheduler I would imagine along with running right in the server.

Comment: Have a look at [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_parallel_ex.htm). It's really designed for parallelization of update tasks, but perhaps that will do what you wanted. Best of luck.

Comment: Also was looking at DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE. Thanks guys. I'll take it from here. Appreciate ya'll. and I don't like how you guys edited my original question. Your taking the humanity out of things. Have a nice one.

Comment: Would it be helpful to use parallel query? This manual section may be relevant: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/using-parallel.html#GUID-3E2AE088-2505-465E-A8B2-AC38813EA355

Comment: @ChadLomax, just for future reference - it is common practice on stackoverflow to edit out greetings like "please" and "hi everyone" etc. - it's nothing personal, it just improves the question for readability and removing distraction. Cheers :)